# wp_enqueue_script not working?

Tags: theme-development, javascript

Excuse me, I'm very new to PHP and WordPress, but I'm trying to link to an exterenal js file called **trans.js**, that relies on jQuery. Here is the code at the beginning of the header.php:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/trans.js"></script>
```

and here is the enqueue within the functions.php

```
function twentytwelve_scripts_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_scripts_styles' );

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/trans.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Yet it still does not link up with the **trans.js** — does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2):

You could use only one function to do all because it's the same hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method() {
   //global $wp_styles; //here no use unless you have to use it in a conditional stylesheet for example
   wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
   wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/trans.js',array( 'jquery'), null, false );
   );
}
```

It's no use modifying the `header.php`, actually it's better to handle scripts and stylesheets in `functions.php` (or in a plugin) than hard coding templates. The recommanded way is to enqueue your stylesheets and scripts because you get a better control (dependencies, load, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you place the below code snippet in your functions.php then, trans.js file should be available in the source. You don't need to change the code in header.php.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/trans.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery